# How to design this MySQL Structure?

Tags: php, mysql

Ok so here is my problem.

I have a selection of items, their names are;

UAT-1
UAT-2
UAT-3

Each item has 'sections', however not every item has the same sections as the previous. For example, UAT-1 will have the sections - 'Red', 'Green', 'Blue'.

UAT-2 will have the seconds - 'Red', 'Brown', 'Purple'

UAT-3 will ahve the sections - 'Gold', 'Silver', 'Red'

What is the best way to design MySQL table(s) for this problem? I was thinking something along the lines of;

items

```
+-----+-----------+
|id   |item_name  |
|-----|-----------|
|1    |UAT-1      |
|2    |UAT-2      |
+-----+-----------+
```

sections

```
+-------------------------------+
|id   |section_name |belongs_to |
|-----|-------------|-----------|
|1    |Red          |1          |
|2    |Green        |1          |
|3    |Blue         |2          |
|4    |Purple       |1          |
|     |             |           |
|     |             |           |
+-------------------------------+
```

However how would I deal with a case where a two sections belong to one item?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you're fine this way. Why would duplicated colors for a given section be an issue? When you 'select * from sections where belongs_to = #' you'll get all three parts since you have a unique ID.

Comment: I just wasn't sure that having lots of duplicate data in a database is good practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to add an intermediate table. This lets your "items" and "sections" live as distinct records.

Items:

```
+-----+-----------+
|id   |item_name  |
|-----|-----------|
|1    |UAT-1      |
|2    |UAT-2      |
+-----+-----------+
```

Sections:

```
+--------------------+
|id   |section_name  |
|-----|--------------|
|1    |Red           |
|2    |Green         |
|3    |Blue          |
|4    |Purple        |
+--------------------+
```

ItemsSections:

```
+---------------+
|item  |section |
|---------------|
|1     |1       |
|1     |2       |
|1     |4       |
|2     |3       |
+---------------+
```

You would get the sections for a specific item with a query like:

```
SELECT
    Sections.*
FROM
    Sections
    RIGHT JOIN ItemsSections
        ON Sections.id = ItemsSections.Section
WHERE
    ItemsSections.item = 1
```

Comment: Sorry to say this, but your select statement doesn't make much sense. If you want to get the sections for one item you will either inner join ItemSections and Sections or use an in clause on ItemSections or use an exists clause on ItemSections. There is no need at all for outer joins here.

Comment: You shouldn't be sorry to say it. It was a bit silly to join against Items, since it provided all output (instead of output for a specific ID, as described). Feel free to suggest other queries or approaches.

Comment: As said, you don't need an outer join here, because there must exist no ItemSections with non-existent Sections. You can use an inner join instead of a right outer join (which I would not use anyhow, because people are used to left outer joins, so right outer joins are much harder to read). You can also do: select * from sections where id in (select section from itemsections where item = 1);

Comment: Also this MySQL Query doesn't work. It outputs the section_name from the section table.

Comment: Subselects aren't normally my first choice for experimenting; it might be informative to select `*`, for example, to see all of the data that's involved, or to tack on a join to Items and drop the `WHERE` clause. I also like outer joins for experimentation because you see the cases where there's no corresponding row in the other tables. Around left-vs-right, you're basically saying to avoid right joins because nobody uses right joins. I'll flip that around -- you should use right joins often so that people learn to read them. It's subjective.

Comment: @GargantuChet apologies - I meant it is out putting the item_name in the item table.

Edit: Nevermind, it does work! I must be tired!

Answer (score 1):

For an n:m relation you would usually have two base tables and one relation table:

```
items
+-----+-----------+
|id   |item_name  |
|-----|-----------|
|1    |UAT-1      |
|2    |UAT-2      |
|3    |UAT-3      |
+-----+-----------+

sections
+-------------------+
|id   |section_name |
|-----|-------------|
|1    |Red          |
|2    |Green        |
|3    |Blue         |
|4    |Brown        |
|5    |Purple       |
|6    |Gold         |
|7    |Silver       |
+-------------------

item_sections
+--------------------+
|id_item |id_section |
|--------|-----------|
|1       |1          |
|1       |2          |
|1       |3          |
|2       |1          |
|2       |4          |
|2       |5          |
|3       |1          |
|3       |6          |
|3       |7          |
+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

UAT-1 will have the sections - 'Red', 'Green', 'Blue'.

UAT-2 will have the seconds - 'Red', 'Brown', 'Purple'

UAT-3 will ahve the sections - 'Gold', 'Silver', 'Red'

```
+-----+-----------+  +-----+--------------+
|id   |item_name  |  |id   |section_name  |
|-----|-----------|  |-----|--------------|
|1    |UAT-1      |  |1    |Red           |
|2    |UAT-2      |  |2    |Green         |
|3    |UAT-3      |  |3    |Blue          |
+-----+-----------+  |4    |Brown         |
                     |5    |Purple        |
                     |6    |Gold          |
                     |7    |Silver        |
                     +-----+--------------+

+-------------------------------+
|id   |section_id   |item_id    |
|-----|-------------|-----------|
|1    |1            |1          |
|2    |2            |1          |
|3    |3            |1          |
|4    |1            |2          |
|5    |4            |2          |
|6    |5            |2          |
|7    |6            |3          |
|8    |7            |3          |
|9    |1            |3          |
+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: There should be 1 more table for sections to remove ambiguity

Comment: I thought about your method... this means there will be lots of duplicate entries - is this good practice?

Comment: Note that the id column in the third table serves no apparent purpose.

Comment: @TomSothcott there you go